# Remove default "Last login:" message in Mac OS X terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

Every time I open a Terminal window, I'm greeted with this message:

```
Last login: Mon Nov 14 21:00:58 on ttys000
```

It bothers me a bit. Is there any way to remove this message from when I open a shell?

Answer (score 19):

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

Comment: Kind of... I have a custom MOTD in `/etc/motd`, is there any way to preserve that while still silencing the `Last login:` banner?

Comment: @esqew I don't know. I didn't find anything in `man motd` or `man login`.

Comment: This doesn't work on Yosemite, see tons of details and solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15769615/6320039